# I have three table views all django-table2 when I set the table title in one view it is changed for each view

Tags: django-tables2

In views.py the view table view is defined

```
    class CompletedClassList(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
        table_class = ClassTable
        table_class.title='Completed Classes'
        filterset_class = ClassFilter
    
        template_name = "classes/class_list.html"
        table_pagination = {"per_page": 20}
    
            def get_queryset(self):
                today = datetime.date.today()
                completed_classes = Class.objects.filter(class_start_date__lte=today)
                return completed_classes
```

Then in my template I call the table title like this:

```
    <div class="row col=md-12 may-form-space">
       <div class="col-md-3 text-md-left">
           <label class="may-form-section">{{ table.title }}</label>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the `table_class.title` attribute is a class level attribute. That stays the same for all `CompletedClassList` type objects. You would want to make it an attribute associated with the `self` like `self.title` in an `__init__` constructor or something. I hope [this resource](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class) can help you.

Comment: I thought I had copied more code ... I actually have 3 classes defined.  class CompletedClassList(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):, class ClassList(SingleTableMixin, FilterView): and class FutureClassList(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):  That all use the same table class "ClassTable".   You are probably right in that the last one loaded is the title that is used by all.    Is there a way to pass a title parameter to the table_class so that I can do a self.title?

Comment: My guess would be that in `ClassTable` you have a `title` parameter that is declared as a class object. If you were to make a `setTitle(self, new_title)` function that made `self.title = new_title` I think you would be able to stop having this issue. I am assuming you have `title` defined similarly to how you have `table_class` defined in  `CompletedClassList`.

Comment: Nano.   This is exactly along the lines of my thought but I could not make it work.   I could set the title all day long in the table class but if I tried to set it in the View it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up on this issue and instead used

```
{{ request.resolver_match.url_name }}
```

in my template instead.   Although not an optimal solution it certainly was acceptable for my needs.